# Using Qwinsta to export a shortened list of disconnected sessions

Tags: powershell, trim

I need to create an application in Powershell which will list the "Disconnected" remote sessions, it must output the username and the ID of the session which will later be used with rwinsta to remove the session

I found a script on stackoverflow which almost does the proof of concept by searching for the sessions and providing a shortened list which shows only the Username and Session ID but I am struggling to resolve formatting issues.  The Foreach and replace is trimming whitespaces and causing the rows to switch columns.

```
function Get-TSSessions
{
    param ($ComputerName = "SERVER")
    qwinsta /server:$ComputerName | ForEach-Object {$_.Trim() -replace "\s+","," } | ConvertFrom-Csv
}

Get-TSSessions -ComputerName "SERVER2016" | ft -Property USERNAME, ID -AutoSize
```

I then get the following out:

```
USERNAME      ID
--------      --
0             Disc
1             Conn
Administrator 5
6             Disc
65536         Listen
```

If I remove the ForEach-Object {$_.Trim() -replace "\s+","," } from the Qwinsta command and then remove the Format-Table -Property USERNAME, ID -Autosize from the Get-TSSessions - I get the following table:

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
 console                                     1  Conn
 31c5ce94259d4...  Administrator             5  Active
                   admin2                    6  Disc
 31c5ce94259d4...                        65536  Listen
 rdp-tcp                                 65537  Listen
```

As you can see, the results in the first table are being moved to the empty space to the left when that column does not contain an entry so the two disconnected sessions do not show the correct Username and ID.

I basically just need the Username and ID columns from the second table to be shown.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Just use task manager and look at the users tab

Comment: Task manager will not be accessible by the end user

Comment: Why are you giving them access to powershell if they can't be trusted with task manager then?

Comment: They will not have access to powershell - there will be a GUI in front of this and the users have very limited access to desktops. essentially I need a GUI for qwinsta and rwinsta commands and filters in place to only allow selection of specific users through a combobox. The GUI part will be added after I can get the script working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Updated based on clearer description of the problem**

It seems `qwinsta.exe` outputs its text in fixed-width columns, so the following should correctly replace the spaces to give valid CSV output:

```
function Get-TSSessions
{
    param ($ComputerName = "SERVER")

    qwinsta /server:$ComputerName |
        ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "\s{2,18}","," } | 
            ConvertFrom-Csv
}

Get-TSSessions -ComputerName "SERVER2016" |
    Where-Object State -eq 'Disc' |
        Format-Table UserName, ID -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks boxdog, sorry about the confusion. I have adjusted the question now.

Comment: Thank you boxdog - I have got around to testing this and it does exactly what I needed! I am making a few additions to it and will post it once complete in case someone else has the need for it.